# Plugins not getting properly installed

Tags: ruby-on-rails

i am having this annoying problem when deploying rails plugins. I can install them by downloading the source and putting it in the vendor/plugins directory, But i want to do it with the easy command line. I am trying to install the will_paginate plugin.

tried this command `ruby script/plugin install git://github.com/mislav/will_paginate.git`
that doesn't work, i tried this one as well `ruby script/plugin install http://github.com/mislav/will_paginate.git`

the problem i am getting is, There is no error while installing the plugin from command line, but rather there is an empty folder created inside vendor/plugins directory by the name of `will_paginate`, And the folder is empty. Any solutions for this?

thanks.

Comment: Which version of Rails are you using? Version older than 2.0.2 do not support installing plugins from git repositories.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you don't have git installed. Are you using Windows? If so, you'll have to download and configure a command-line git client.

If you do have git installed and configured correctly, alternatively, from your root rails directory you could try:

```
git clone git://github.com/mislav/will_paginate.git vendor/plugins/will_paginate
```

Answer (score 0):

ruby script/plugin install git://github.com/mislav/will_paginate.git

That should work for you.  For reference, [here is the blog post from github](http://github.com/blog/25-git-support-for-rails-plugins).  According to that post, this was supported beginning in Rails 2.0.2, so you'll need to be using at least that version of Rails and have git installed locally.

Comment: That one is not working. Still does the same. adds an empty folder named will_paginate to the vendor/plugins directory.

Comment: Which version of Rails and which version of Git are you using?  I'm curious if the issue is that git is not installed, or accessible via your $PATH.